# machine.config appSettings are null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, machine.config

In my machine.config file I have the following

```
<configuration>
    ....
    <appSettings>
        <add key="key" value="value"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to retrieve it on an asp page by using

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"];
```

and it returns null every time.

Comment: Are you referring to web.config... ?

Comment: Do you have a `clear` node somewhere else?

Comment: There are two `machine.config` files if you are in a 64-bit environment. One for Framework64 and one for Framework. Make sure it is in the right one, or both.

Comment: @vcsjones your right, thats solved it :)

Comment: @harryovers great, Darin wrote it up with the full details. Credit goes to him.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You probably put it in the wrong machine.config. Remember that there is the same machine.config for .NET 2.0 and 3.5 as they both target CLR 2.0 (`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\`) and a separate machine.config for .NET 4.0 (`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\`).

Also remember that if you are running a 64 bit OS the folders are `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\` and `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\` respectively. So make sure you have put the key in the correct machine.config that correspond to the framework version you are targeting in your ASP.NET application as well as the x86 or x64 bit.

So you get a machine.config per CLR version and *bitness* (no idea if such word exists).

Comment: I don't believe there is a machine.config for 3.5, since it is by runtime.

Comment: @vcsjones, no there isn't a separate machine.config for .NET 3.5. It is the same as for .NET 2.0. I will update my answer as it is confusing.