# machine specific config settings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

I have an application that gets deployed to a load balanced environment. This application is an asp.net mvc4 application.

I have settings (appsettings & httpheaders) in the web.config for each server. Rather than managing them during deployment, is there a way to set them on the machine and available in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your specific settings in the `machine.config` file on each server. You'll then be able to access those settings, as you would an app setting in `the web.config`:

```
string setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["machine.somekey"];
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431709/machine-config-appsettings-are-null#answer-8431790) for the location of the machine.config file.

Comment: Cool - where is the machine config file located?

Comment: Is the web.config or machine.config file I should update in that folder?

Comment: The machine.config file is located in your .NET framework installation directory. In my case (Windows 8), the 32-bit version of the .NET framework 4 machine.config file is located in: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config . The 64-bit version is located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config.