# Centralised Connection String for multiple application asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, machine.config

I have a web server with multiple application running. All the application have their `web.config` file. If the database password changes due to Policy I have to manually change the password in each of `web.config` files in the app setting section.

I was reading about the connection string setting in [`machine.config` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431709/machine-config-appsettings-are-null).

Now my question is if I put connection string in appsetting section of `machine.config` with name `ConnectionString` and same in my `web.config` file will it overwrite the `machine.config` file values.

In my `machine.config` following is the setting

```
<configuration>
  ....
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="value"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

similarly in my `web.config` file

```
<configuration>
  ....
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="value"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And I get the value in my code as below

```
string conString=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
```

will I get the overloaded value?

Comment: Yes the value in `Web.Config` will override the value present in your `Machine.Config` file.

Answer (score 1):

What's going to help you out here is to store your connection string(s) in .config file and then reference them either using the `file=""` attribute or the `configSource=""` attribute.

Here's an excellent question and answer that talks about the differences between the two and shows you how to implement them:

[ASP.NET web.config: configSource vs. file attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940004/asp-net-web-config-configsource-vs-file-attributes)

Comment: the problem with the file is it overrides the `web.config` value but I want the reverse. So can do this in the link which you have provided?